# Путь до html файла на хостинге

Tags: html, инструменты-разработчика

Как я могу определить путь до html файла на хостинге через инструменты разработчика, особенно когда сайт интегрирован в какую нибудь запутанную CMS, это становится проблемой для меня,
до css и js файлов добираюсь относительно легко, а с html проблемы.

Comment: html обычно генерируется на лету, и файлов просто не существует

Comment: все зависит от cms и от того что за сайт(динамический или полностью статический). Что то может лежать и в бд, ищи файлы с расширением .php(папки views, public, resources)